# How do I perform operations on variables assigned from dictionary objects in Swift?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to get the difference between two values:

```
var lastValue = eminiSP["data"]![0]![4]
var previousDayValue = eminiSP["data"]![1]![4]
var netChange = lastValue - previousDayValue  //throws error
```

I'm assuming it has to do with the types, but how do I convert lastValue and previousDayValue so that I can perform an operation? `previousDayValue.doubleValue` or `Double(previousDayValue)` throw an error as well. Maybe I'm thinking about it from a completely incorrect angle since I'm dealing with dictionaries?

eminiSP["data"]![0] and eminiSP["data"]![1] look like this respectively:

```
(
    "2014-06-05",
    "1918.25",
    "1933.25",
    "1913.5",
    "1931.25",
    "12.75",
    1931,
    30181,
    99537
)
(
    "2014-06-04",
    "1915.75",
    "1919.5",
    "1908.75",
    "1918.25",
    "3.5",
    "1918.25",
    19024,
    86475
)
```

Here is the full code:

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import Cocoa

func getJSON(urlToRequest: String) -> NSData{
    return NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: urlToRequest))
}

func parseJSON(inputData: NSData) -> NSDictionary{
    var error: NSError?
    var dataDictionary: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(inputData,     options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &error) as NSDictionary
return dataDictionary
}

var parsedJSON =   parseJSON(getJSON("http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/CME/ESU2014.json?auth_token=REMOVED_AUTH_TOKEN"))

let eminiSP = parsedJSON

var lastValue = eminiSP["data"]![0]![4]
var previousDayValue = eminiSP["data"]![1]![4]
var netChange = lastValue - previousDayValue  //throws error

println(lastValue)
println(previousDayValue)
println(netChange)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
let a = "123.456"
let b = (a as NSString).doubleValue
```

Comment: tried this: `let lastValue = eminiSP["data"]![0]![4]
let lastValueDouble = (lastValue as NSString).doubleValue` but then I still throw an error.

Comment: Actually, you were correct! I used downcasting with as and it ended up working exactly as I hoped. Here's the snippet I changed: `let netChange = (lastValue as Double) - (previousDayValue as Double) `